# How can i completely disable Code Contracts?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-contracts

I currently have it setup like below.  I had tried checking 'Perform Runtime Contract Checking' and then selecting 'None' but that seems unnecessary.  If I have my project setup like below are code contracts completely disabled?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes

But make sure its set like that for each build configuration, not just release.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2010 SP1 still runs its pesky cccheck.exe processes in that case.